# Contact Form with recaptcha producing 500 error

Tags: php, html, recaptcha, contact-form

I have a contact form with recaptcha that i am trying to set up but produces a 500 error when information is entered and the submit button is clicked. I'm going to bet money that I have done something stupid as I'm not the greatest with PHP, so if I post my code here, would anyone be able to spot anything wrong?

This is the Contact Form itself.

```
<form class="email" action="mailer.php" method="post">
    <p>Name:</p>
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <p>E-mail:</p>
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <p>Subject:</p>
    <input type="text" name="subject" />
    <p>Message:</p>
    <textarea name="message"></textarea></p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.recaptcha.net/challenge?k=6Le8_t4SAAAAACIxacT6Xn8NVvDa93loylG-L6mk"></script>
    <noscript>
        <iframe src="http://api.recaptcha.net/noscript?k=PUBLICKEYGOESHERE" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge">
    </noscript>
    <input class="send" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

And this is the mailer.php

```
<?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
if ($_POST['email'] != '')
{
    $privatekey = "6Le8_t4SAAAAAME8kuqO1bvzcSWmGytwISUYLo3w";
    $resp       = recaptcha_check_answer($privatekey, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"], $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
    if (!$resp->is_valid)
    {
        die("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly.
Go back and try it again." . "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
    }
    else
    {
        /* Set e-mail recipient */
        $myemail = "mandy@smarterbookkeeping.com.au";

        /* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
        $name    = check_input($_POST['name'], "Enter your name");
        $subject = check_input($_POST['subject'], "Enter a subject");
        $email   = check_input($_POST['email']);
        $message = check_input($_POST['message'], "Write your message");
        $captcha = check_input($_POST['captcha']);

        /* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
        if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
        {
            show_error("E-mail address not valid");
        }

        /* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
        $message = "

Name: $name
E-mail: $email
Subject: $subject

Message:
$message

";
        /* Send the message using mail() function */
        mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

        /* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
        header('Location: thanks.php');
        exit();

        /* Functions we used */
        function check_input($data, $problem = '')
        {
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
            if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
            {
                show_error($problem);
            }
            return $data;
        }
        function show_error($myError)
        {
?>
<html>
<body>

<p>Please correct the following error:</p>
<strong><?php
            echo $myError;
?></strong>
<p>Hit the back button and try again</p>

</body>
</html>
<?php
            exit();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I have the recaptchalib in the right place, same goes for the thanks.php. I'm not very good at PHP, but this one has me stumped.

Comment: Check you log files, they may include more specific information on the error

Comment: Do you have a link to recaptchalib.php ?

Comment: How do you mean link to recaptchalib? Its got the php require to it up the top its like the first line.

Comment: I mean I want to see the class, because I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Following on from @Ryoku when asking a Q on SO, assume that those who are trying to help you may be unfamiliar with the specific libraries you're using. By providing links/additional info, you greatly increase the chance of getting a good answer. In any case, welcome to SO.

Comment: oh yeah of course I thought you ment something else.
http://codebin.org/view/c6fe96b7

Comment: Could this be related? https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/recaptcha/dDkE3pIB4Eg
or there are a few others: https://groups.google.com/group/recaptcha/search?hl=es-419&group=recaptcha&q=error+500&qt_g=Buscar+en+este+grupo

Comment: Thanks for linking those, ill go through and have a look, iv also been looking through the log files but cannot find anything on the 500 error? do you know what i should be searching for specifically to find it in the logs?

Comment: Could you not turn php error reporting on http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php, so you can see what php is complaining about rather than a 500 response.